# Autogenerate composite key in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, composite-primary-key

I have a composite primary key {shop_id, product_id} for SQLite
Now, I want an auto-increment value for product_id which resets to 1 if shop id is changed. Basically, I want auto-generated composite key 
e.g.

Shop ID   Product Id

1         1

1 2

1 3

2 1

2 2

3 1

Can I achieve this with auto-increment? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal Sqlite tables are B*-trees that use a 64-bit integer as their key. This is called the [rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). When inserting a row, if a value is not explicitly given for this, one is generated. An `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column acts as an alias for this rowid. The `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, which can only be used on said `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, contrary to the name, merely alters how said rowid is calculated - if you leave out a value, one will be created whether that keyword is present or not, because it's really the rowid and must have a number. Details [here](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). (rowid values are generally generated in increasing, but not necessarily sequential, order, and shouldn't be treated like a row number or anything like that, btw).

Any primary key other than a single `INTEGER` column is treated as a unique index, while the rowid remains the true primary key (Unless it's a [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table), and is not autogenerated. So, no, you can't (easily) do what you want.

I would probably work out a database design where you have a table of shops, a table of products, each with their own ids, and a junction table that establishes a many-to-many relation between the two. This keeps the product id the same between stores, which is probably going to be less confusing to people - I wouldn't expect the same item to have a different SKU in two different stores of the same chain, for instance.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE stores(store_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                  , address TEXT
                    -- etc
                   );
CREATE TABLE product(prod_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                   , name TEXT
                     -- etc
                   );
CREATE TABLE inventory(store_id INTEGER REFERENCES stores(store_id)
                     , prod_id INTEGER REFERENCES product(prod_id)
                     , PRIMARY KEY(store_id, prod_id)) WITHOUT ROWID;
```