# How can I add prefix to SQLite auto_increment field?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, auto-increment

Is there a way to add prefix to an auto increment field in SQLite so that when new records are added, the auto increment value contain the prefix?

Comment: No. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332718/autogenerate-composite-key-in-sqlite/55333152#55333152) to a similar question for details.

Comment: If your prefixes are always the same or calculable, you can add them in `SELECT` statement. Numbers key always better and faster.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to add prefix to an auto increment field in sqlite so
>   that when new records are added, the auto increment value contain the
>   prefix?

**No**.

- Such a column is a special column that is an alias of the **rowid** column. Such a column MUST be an integer value.
- The intended use of such a column is really to be able to uniquely identify a row.

---

## BUT.....

However, it would be possible to always return a value with a prefix e.g. by using

```
SELECT 'prefix'||mycolumn FROM mytable;
```

## Working Example

:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (mycolumn INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, myothercolumn TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable (myothercolumn) VALUES('Fred'),('Mary'),('Jane'),('andsoon');
SELECT 'myprefix'||mycolumn, myothercolumn FROM mytable;
```

- Note there is no need for the AUTOINCREMENT keyword that only imposes a constraint but is inefficient [AUTOINCREMENT](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

## Result

[image]

## Mimicking what you want

It would be possible to replicate what you want e.g. :-

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mytable2manager;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable2 (mycolumn TEXT, myothercolumn TEXT);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS mytable2manager AFTER INSERT ON mytable2 BEGIN
    UPDATE mytable2 SET mycolumn = 'myprefix'||(SELECT count() FROM mytable2) WHERE rowid = new.rowid;
END;
INSERT INTO mytable2 (myothercolumn) VALUES('Fred'),('Mary'),('Jane'),('andsoon');
SELECT * FROM mytable2;
```

- This creates a table along with a TRIGGER and then inserts the same data as above.
- The TRIGGER is actioned whenever a row is inserted and in this case it mimics what the SQLite auto-generation of the rowid value does prefixing the value

  - it could alternatively use `SET mycolumn = 'myprefix'||rowid`
  - Without the TRIGGER mycolumn would be null

## Result

[image]

## Additional

You could even have the TRIGGER in the mimicking method apply different prefixes. The following example uses a different prefix when the value in the myothercolumn starts with an **M**

:-

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mytable2manager;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable2 (mycolumn TEXT, myothercolumn TEXT);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS mytable2manager AFTER INSERT ON mytable2 BEGIN
    UPDATE mytable2 SET mycolumn = CASE WHEN substr(new.myothercolumn,1,1) = 'M' THEN 'myprefix' ELSE 'myotherprefix' END||(SELECT count() FROM mytable2) WHERE rowid = new.rowid;
        -- UPDATE mytable2 SET mycolumn = 'myprefix'||rowid WHERE rowid = new.rowid;
END;
INSERT INTO mytable2 (myothercolumn) VALUES('Fred'),('Mary'),('Jane'),('andsoon');
SELECT * FROM mytable2;
```

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably to use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select ('prefix' || id) as new_id, t.*
    from t;
```